# How to add up the row values

Tags: java

in this java code i am trying to read each row from the `read.txt` file, but i want to get the line number if i pass a parameter

For example:- `read.txt` contains

```
2
2
4
5
6
7
7
8
8
9
```

i am passing the parameter 9

then the program should return line number 10

because the value i gave as parameter present in line number 10
 how can i do this?

here is what i have tried
Java code:

```
import java.io.*;

class CountRows
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        setForSum("read.txt",9);
    }

    public static void setForSum(String filename,int param2)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fsteam));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
            {
                System.out.println (strLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect if the parameter is `2`

Comment: Line numbers where 2 is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;

class CountRows
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        setForSum("read.txt",9);
    }

    public static void setForSum(String filename,int param2)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            int i = 0;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
            {
                i++;
                if(param2 == Integer.parseInt(strLine){ 
                   //print the i i.e line number
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a counter variable

```
int counter=0;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
{
  if(counter==param2)
    System.out.println (strLine);

  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use counter for it.

```
try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            int cnt=1;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
            {
              if(strLine.contain(Integer.toString(param2)))  
                {                   
                System.out.println (strLine + "is present at line no "+ cnt);
                }
                cnt++;
            }
            in.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too.

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\read.txt"));
    int val=1;
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        if(sc.next().equals("9")){
            System.out.println("Line number "+val);
        }
        val++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list to hold int values. Which could look like:

```
public static ArrayList<int> setForSum(String filename,int param2) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;

        ArrayList<int> numberList = new ArrayList<int>();            

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                if (Integer.parseInt(strLine) == param2) {
                    numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(strLine));
                }
                //break;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        in.close();
        return numberList;
    }
```

Using this way will allow you to get multiple results from the file. If you uncomment the break it will work with only 1 record though the the other answers are probably faster in that case.